# can't insert data to table in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, insert

i have 2 actions .. one for User and i can add data to User table but for Order table my code didn't works and got catch error

this is my user code (Action in Controller)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {
        UserRepository blUser = new UserRepository();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (blUser.Add(user))
            {
                return Json(new JsonData() { Success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new JsonData() { Success = false });
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new JsonData() { Success = false });
        }

    }
```

and (UserRepository):

```
public class UserRepository : IDisposable
{
    private HairCut.Models.MVCHairDresserDBEntities db = null;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        db = new HairCut.Models.MVCHairDresserDBEntities();
    }

    public bool Add(HairCut.Models.User entity, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Users.Add(entity);
            if (autoSave)
                return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i just change User word to Order but when try to insert data to table i got catch and return false

Order code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reserve(int select, int user,int hdId)
    { 
             Order order = new Order();
             order.HairDresserId =hdId;
             order.UserId = user;
             order.timeCome =  (select).ToString();
             order.timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddh");
             order.confirm = true;
             OrderRepository blOrder = new OrderRepository();
             if (blOrder.Add(order))
               {
                 return Json(new JsonData() { Success = true });
               }
               else
               {
                 return Json(new JsonData() { Success = false });
               }

    }
```

OrderRepository is similar UserRepository. so why cant insert ? where is my wrong ?

every time use breackpoint and debug my codes got catch in code `return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());`

OrderRepository have 2 foreignkey. when i checked entity quick watch, helper show me 2 extra field ( User and HairDresser with null value ) .. maybe i need set value to these ?

or maybe need create MetaData class to check validation like User values ( but i don't think this is my problem )

Comment: an empty try catch can only hide the error. Why don't you try to remove that empty try/catch in the Add method and look if you have any error there?

Comment: Yes, catch and inspect the exception and make sure your FKs both exist in the database (nav properties can be null).

Comment: you are correct - -".. maybe i need set value to these ?" Populate your FKs and you will be OK

Comment: a catch which hides an unexpected error (and also doesn't log anything) is an anti-pattern. If you hadn't done that suppression you might have found the problem straight away